# Apache Solr: Index-time field boosts

Tags: solr-boost

I am searching a product database with Solr and edismax parser and I want to make hits in certain fields weigh more than hits in other fields.
Let's say every product has a *name* and a *short_description* but also other fields which may be dynamically. All fields are supposed to be searched but *name* and *short_description* are supposed to be more (or less) important than the rest.

I know this can be done at query time with the **qf** Parameter ([Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)). 
I can see that it works. Documents are perfectly scored up and down depending on the supplied fields.

The problem is I obviously need to mention all fields to be searched and the other fields may be dynamically. Maybe I can get all relevant fields somehow and send them, but I would prefer a solution at index time.

I kind of inherited the code for this, what the code is doing right now is sending the following JSON to index:

```
{
"add": {
    "boost": 1,
    "doc": {
        (...)
        "name": {
            "boost": 0.3,
            "value": "product name #1"
        },
        (...)
        "short_description": {
            "boost": 3,
            "value": "some text"
        },
```

I would expect a hit in *short_description* to be boosted with value 3 and and a hit in *name* be boosted with 0.3, i.e. scored down compared to everything else (default document value 1).

What happens is that documents with a hit in *name* score the same as documents with a hit in *short_description*.

(search for **mordor**)

```
      {
    (...)
    "name": "mordor",
    "short_description": "this is a random description",
    (...)
    "score": 3.5821834
  },
  {
    (...)
    "name": "this is a random description",
    "short_description": "mordor",
    (...)
    "score": 3.5821834
  }
```

I found [this document](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_field_.28or_document.29_boosting_and_query_boosting.3F) saying that:

> Index time field boosts are worthless if you set them on every document.

Is this why it isn't working? Or am I doing something wrong?
If it isn't working like that, is there any way to enter something like a wildcard into the **qf** parameter at query time (i.e. **qf=name^3 short_description^0.3 ***)?

Comment: What is the definition of the fields you're indexing? index time boosts require norms, so if the omitNorms is true, index time boosts will not be stored.

Comment: I took that into account and made sure the fields were set to omitNorms=false.
   <field name="name" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>
   <field name="short_description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="false"/>